# Embed pdf content in pdf layer

Tags: pdf, embed, layer

I just registered. I try to address the following case:

Given a basic pdf (a simple, single raster image), I want to get to:

- Create a pdf (empty initially), in which I create a layer, in which I embed the raster image of the input_pdf, and mark said layer as visible and not_printable.

Are there tools to do it?

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: In which programming language do you want to implement this? Which pdf library do you use?

Comment: Your question is not acceptable on Stack Overflow: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."

Comment: Okay, the question is exploratory, it is because although I program in python, I am not at all clear that there is a library to handle layers in that way. Thank you very much for the user iPDFdev code C#, I will have to read the license terms. I would appreciate library info in python to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not specify a language or a library you use, here it is a solution in C#:

```
// Extract the page content from the source file.
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("input.pdf");
PDFFile source = new PDFFile(stream);
PDFPageContent pageContent = source.ExtractPageContent(0);
stream.Close();

PDFFixedDocument document = new PDFFixedDocument();
document.OptionalContentProperties = new PDFOptionalContentProperties();
PDFPage page = document.Pages.Add();

// Create an optional content group (layer) for the extracted page content.
PDFOptionalContentGroup ocg = new PDFOptionalContentGroup();
ocg.Name = "Embedded page";
ocg.VisibilityState = PDFOptionalContentGroupVisibilityState.AlwaysVisible;
ocg.PrintState = PDFOptionalContentGroupPrintState.NeverPrint;

// Draw the extracted page content in the layer
page.Canvas.BeginOptionalContentGroup(ocg);
page.Canvas.DrawFormXObject(pageContent, 0, 0, page.Width, page.Height);
page.Canvas.EndOptionalContentGroup();

// Build the display tree for the optional content
PDFOptionalContentDisplayTreeNode ocgNode = new PDFOptionalContentDisplayTreeNode(ocg);
document.OptionalContentProperties.DisplayTree.Nodes.Add(ocgNode);

using (FileStream output = File.Create("EmbedPageAsLayer.pdf"))
{
    document.Save(output); 
}
```

The output PDF file is available here: https://github.com/o2solutions/pdf4net/blob/master/GettingStarted/EmbedPageAsLayer/EmbedPageAsLayer.pdf